# UnitofWork over Custom IdentityDbContext doesn't save changes also Current User always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

**The problem is:**

> when I Inject unit of work at any service it doen't save changes, when
>   I debug it I found change tracker doesn't have values changed Also,
>   HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name always Null

**IdentityDbContext Implementation**

```
public class IdentityAppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>, IIdentityDbContext
    {
        public IdentityAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityAppDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            : base(options)
        {
            CurrentUserName = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
        }
....
}
```

**Identity registration**

```
services.AddDbContext<IdentityAppDbContext>(options =>             options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName)));

                services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityAppDbContext>()
                    .AddUserManager<IdentityUserManager>()
                    .AddUserStore<IdentityUserStore>()
                    .AddRoleManager<IdentityRoleManager>()
                    .AddRoleStore<IdentityRoleStore>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**UnitOfWork Implementation**

```
public sealed class IdentityUnitOfWork : UnitOfWorkBase<IdentityAppDbContext>, IIdentityUnitOfWork
{
    public IdentityUnitOfWork(IdentityAppDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

}
```

**UnitOfWork Base**

```
 public class UnitOfWorkBase<TContext> : IUnitOfWorkBase<TContext>
        where TContext : IEfCoreDbContext
    {
        public TContext Context { get; }
        public UnitOfWorkBase(TContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }
        public int SaveChanges()
        {
            return Context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

**UnitOfWork Injection**

```
    services.TryAddScoped<IIdentityUnitOfWork, IdentityUnitOfWork>();
```

Comment: The `HttpContext.User` will not be populated until inside a controller action - it will probably be null inside the constructors as you are doing it because you will not actually have and `HttpContext` until you are inside a request (controller action).

Comment: For ` HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name`, have you sign in your application? What is your current `Startup.cs`? What is the full code for using `UnitOfWorkBase`?

Comment: Yes, I'm already logged in, also it is worked with me before in another DbContext not in IdentityDbContext